# IOS: Collection view image position changing

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using `UICollectionView` to display images which are loading from the device photo gallery. I'm using Asset Library to load the images. When I'm scrolling the `UICollectionView`, images are changing their positions inside the collection view (not duplicating). Therefore when I clicked on an image, different image is loading. Any help?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *GalleryImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    url=@"";
    Document* doc = [galleryImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    GalleryImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    url = doc.path;
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    NSURL *referenceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    __block UIImage *returnValue = nil;
    [library assetForURL:referenceURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
     {
         returnValue = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]];
         GalleryImageView.image = returnValue;
         returnValue = nil;
         documentID= [dbutil getDocumentIDbyPath:url];
         GalleryImageView.tag = documentID;

     }
            failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
     }];



    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?